# Editing files on Google Cloud Engine VM

Tags: sftp, google-compute-engine

I have recently setup a VM on Google Cloud to develop and host my web site/application. The setup went fine, and I even have gcloud SDK up and running. I also have Apache installed and configured. My question is how do I setup my editing environment (PHP Storm) and upload my files? They seem to have the ports for FTP and SFTP blocked.

Answer (score 0):

FTP uses a clear-text protocol and is thus not recommended. To use SFTP:

1. Make sure you can ssh to your instance: `gcutil --project=<project> ssh <instance>`. This does two things: (a) makes sure that port 22 is open on your VM, and (b) propagates your private key to the instance, if it's not already there.
2. [Configure PHP Storm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/03/drag-drop-project-files-to-remote-hosts-in-phpstorm/) to use the [*Key pair*](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/deployment-connection-tab.html) authentication mechanism using the key `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` to log in to the instance.

That's it.